# Как автоматически изменить значение в plus/minus buttons при достижении определённых условий

Tags: javascript, tilda

Простите мою некомпетентность, я не специалист в java script (и вообще не программист), но хочу разобраться. Помогите, пожалуйста, голову сломал уже. Задача, вроде, простая.

Есть вот такая тестовая страничка на Тильде: http://project32344.tilda.ws/page27794948.html
В левой части выбор кол-ва элементов, в средней наверху - общее кол-во, в средней внизу - сумма, которая получается перемножением общего кол-ва на цену (price), указанную в правой части при помощи значения в  plus/minus buttons. Это всё стандартные элементы Тильды.

Задача: при достижении определённого общего кол-ва нужно автоматически менять цену, общая сумма, соответственно, должна пересчитываться. Вручную всё работает. Правая часть со значением цены (price) потом будет как-то скрываться. Используется plus/minus, а не что-то другое, т.к. встроенный калькулятор "видит" значения только так или ещё при использовании ползунка с кол-вом. Если проще/иначе можно сделать - хорошо.

Код:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var articles = ['1000','800'];

document.querySelector(".t-input-block").addEventListener("click", callreload);

function callreload(){ 
    
    var quantity = document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']").value;
    
      if (quantity<=3){
          reloadprice(articles[0]);
      }else{
          reloadprice(articles[1]);
      };
};


function reloadprice(a){
    document.querySelector("input[name='price']").value = var a;
};

});

</script>
```

Comment: `.value = var a;` тут не нужен var. Попробуйте установить значение "value" через ".setAttribute".

Comment: Сделал так:

`var attr = document.querySelector("input[name='price']").value;
attr.setAttribute("text", a);`

Но не могу понять, какое имя атрибута использовать в данном случае

Comment: ```document.querySelector("input[name='price']").setAttribute("value", a)```

Comment: Не взлетело, к сожалению (

Comment: а если то что я написал и еще ```document.querySelector("input[name='price']").dispatchEvent(new Event("input"))```, если не сработает input, попробуйте change.

Comment: Так тоже не хочет. А не может быть проблема в `document.querySelector(".t-input-block").addEventListener("click", callreload);`? Я сначала пытался привязаться к плюсу и минусу (при нажатии вызов соответствующей функции), а потом завязался на весь этот блок. Но у меня таких 3 блока и все с одинаковым системным названием класса, которое формируется самой Тильдой, если я правильно понимаю. Можно вообще так делать, как я сделал или лучше по какому-то другому событию вызывать функцию или по такому же, но иначе как-то?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136784/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-aa-mas).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var articles = ['1000', '800'];

  document.querySelectorAll(".t-input-block").forEach((el) => el.addEventListener("click", callreload));

  function callreload() {

    var quantity = document.querySelector("input[name='quantity']").value;

    if (quantity <= 3) {
      reloadprice(articles[0]);
    } else {
      reloadprice(articles[1]);
    };
  };


  function reloadprice(a) {
    document.querySelector("input[name='price']").setAttribute("value", a)
  };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

В `inputs` записываются значения атрибутов `name` этих инпутов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

В `articles` записываете цены, что будут меняться по условию, либо записываете вручную.
`inputPrice` - инпут, откуда берётся цена для подсчёта цены в вашем калькуляторе, туда же будет выводится цена из `price`.
`textCount` - число в "общее количество", по которому считается условие [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее вешается обработчик `input` (ввод значений) на все `input[name="inputs[]"]`, а так же обработчик `click` (нажатие) на кнопки <kbd>-</kbd> и <kbd>+</kbd> рядом с инпутом.

Функция в обработчиках одна и так же - `ChangePrice()`.
В ней мы получаем общее кол-во товаров (переменная `count`), а далее выставляем `inputPrice` значение `value` по условию.

```
var inputs = ['quantity_red', 'quantity_green', 'quantity_blue'],
    articles = [1000, 800],
    inputPrice = document.querySelector('.t-input[name="price"]'),
    textCount = document.querySelector('.t-calc[data-calc-expr="quantity_red + quantity_green + quantity_blue"]');

inputs.forEach(function(name, i) {
  var input = document.querySelector(`.t-input[name="${name}"]`),
      btns = input.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.t-inputquantity__btn');
  input.addEventListener('input', ChangePrice);
  btns.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', ChangePrice);
  });
});

function ChangePrice() {
  var count = Number(textCount.innerText.trim());

  if(count <= 3)
    inputPrice.value = articles[0];
  else 
    inputPrice.value = articles[1];
}
```

---

Код проверял на сайте через консоль, работало в FF отлично.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное описание кода! 
Мне консоль выдаёт ошибку: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentElement')". Ругается на строку 
btns = input.parentElement.querySelectorAll('.t-inputquantity__btn');

Comment: @aa.mas, а селекторы правильно указаны?

Comment: насколько я могу судить - да. Есть сомнение как раз в селекторе .t-inputquantity__btn . Есть t-inputquantity__btn t-inputquantity__btn-minus и t-inputquantity__btn t-inputquantity__btn-plus, но, как я понял, inputquantity__btn это родительский элемент и его как раз Вы и задали. Или я не прав?

Comment: Нет, у вас есть два элемента с классом `t-inputquantity__btn`, отличаются друг от друга наличиями разных классов - `t-inputquantity__btn-minus` и `t-inputquantity__btn-plus`. Но дополнительные классы не используются в коде, используется общий, но берётся сразу две кнопки. `parentElemnt` вернёт элемент в котором находятся эти две кнопки и инпут `t-input` (в вашем случае элемент `t-inputquantity__wrapper`)

Comment: Да, логику я понял, но не понимаю, от чего ошибка и почему у меня код не работает. Перепроверил на синтаксические ошибки, перечитал форумы, но лыжи не едут... Пишут, например, что одна из причин может быть в том, что div загружается позже script и поэтому код "не видит" элементы (как-то так). Но как в Тильде это проверить или переиграть, чтобы было наоборот - не понимаю... Да и в этом ли проблема. Если есть варианты - намекните, попробую перепроверить все возможные.

Comment: @aa.mas, чтобы выполнить код когда блоки загружены, используйте `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {/*СЮДА ВАШ КОД*/});`.

Comment: Ему всё равно не нравится parentElement, ругается прежней ошибкой.